# alternative of time for a seed to a random number generator?

Tags: go

In Go what value can one use as an alternative of **current time**
for a seed to a random number generator?

This simple question came to me as I was following the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1)
where they say the current time in their sandbox environment is fixed.

Comment: Generally, instead of something as deterministic as the current time, you can use another PRNG or even a true source of random to seed the PRNG. This is not specific to Go though, it applies to any programming language. Why would you need that though?

Comment: If you're worried about the `math/rand` PRNG being deterministic (which it is for a reason), you should be using `crypto/rand`

Comment: Anything in the sandbox used by the tour/docs/playground can be assumed to be somewhat deterministic; the random seed is fixed, the time is fixed, and repeated executions of the same code return cached results. None of this matters when running code in any real environment.

Comment: I was asking exactly with the Tour of Go in mind i.e. how to get a random number there.

Comment: You can't really. It's just a test environment to learn how the language works.

Comment: @Adrian Seems I can with the answer given below by Burak. Also the Tour itself says we can, we just need to think how to do it without using current time. Not sure why my question was downvoted. Seems a good question to me, not too obvious how to do that in the Tour. But lately anything is downvoted here in SO...  Seems like all good questions have been asked already :)

Comment: You still can't. If you keep running the same code, you'll keep getting the same results. `crypto/rand` also likely does not have a real random source in the playground. See here for more info on how playground works: https://blog.golang.org/playground

Comment: @Adrian I tried it and it seems to work pretty well. So I am not sure how likely is the likely you mentioned. I needed something simple here, not to dig so deeply at this stage. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `crypto.rand` package to read some random bytes, and convert that to a int64:

```
import (
  "crypto/rand"
  "encoding/binary"
)
...

b:=make([]byte,8)
rand.Read(b)
seed:=binary.BigEndian.Uint64(b)
```

Comment: Just as a warning, this doesn't turn the PRNG into a source of randomness suitable for cryptography!

Comment: Yes, this is simply a random seed value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want access to the `math/rand` convenience functions without the deterministic PRNG, you can create a new secure `rand.Source` yourself.

```
type cryptoSource [8]byte

func (s *cryptoSource) Int63() int64 {
    const mask = (1 << 63) - 1
    crand.Read(s[:])
    i := int64(binary.BigEndian.Uint64(s[:]))
    return i & mask
}

func (cryptoSource) Seed(int64) {}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/sD4fOkE8LeD